# (Client-side) Do I still need to check on method if action is allowed to run if button is disabled?

Tags: javascript, web, client

Do you also need to check the method being called if it's allowed if you already disabled the button?

Just thought of if someone removes the `disabled` property in a button, that method would run.

And to prevent that, just do another check in the method if it's allowed.

It's client side only so nothing unwanted will happen on the server.

On one side I am thinking it is not needed because if someone pokes around the code, he should be expecting something bad will happen.

On another I thought of it might affect something like UX.

Am I just overthinking? Is this over-engineering?

**EDIT** to avoid confusion, Server will be safe and out of this question. With that being said, do you still need to check if a method is allowed to run?

Comment: If user is not supposed to do something, don't let him do

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (misread question):

If you're already doing a server side check, you don't need to do it on the client, unless you really want to reduce the number of requests to the server. It's much simpler to just process the error response sent by the server.

The main problem with doing a client-side check is synchronizing the authorization logic between client and server.

Comment: Uhm, if you read the OP carefully I said client-side. So server is safe. That being said, is checking still necessary?